# Get Android device ID shown in adb

Tags: java, android, adb, uniqueidentifier

How can I get Android device ID to string (with Java code Android 2.2+) that is shown when I connect it to computer ([example from eclipse "Serial number" field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip2re.png)) or enter **"adb devices"** to cmd? I know **it's not ANDROID_ID or telephonyManager.getdeviceId() or Build.SERIAL** but I can't find what is it...

Comment: You want it in android app?

Comment: You can try doing a getprop on "ro.serialno" system property

Comment: @vishalm - ro.serialno empty, ril.serialnumber returns 000000000000. Also, Alex.P said this is not universal way.

Answer (score 4):

the only universal way is to pull the number from USB interface settings:

```
/sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial
```

Other than that it is up to every vendor to choose the way to store the serial number. Some of them choose not to populate `ro.serialno` property.

Comment: can't find android_usb in /sys/class/... Also, I found this number in /cat/proc/cpuinfo

Comment: specific location depends on android version. which one are you using? as for the `/proc/cpuinfo` - this number contains the chipset ID. some vendors may choose to use it (or part or some hash function of it) for the USB serial as well.

Comment: Android 2.3.3 Also, can you tell me if chipset ID (serial=) from /proc/cpuinfo can be found on every Android device?

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` will contain the chip ID for all chipsets supporting it. But it does not help you with finding out the number which `adb devices` shows as very few phone manufacturers use chip ID for USB serial. Unfortunately I do not have any devices that old to check the exact location for that version.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the id shown by the `adb devices` command, then it is indeed `Build.SERIAL`.

The value shown in Eclipse seems to be just a concatenation of `Build.MANUFACTURER`, `Build.MODEL` and `Build.SERIAL`.

At least these are the results when testing on Nexus devices.

Comment: Build.SERIAL returns "unknown" (tried on 3 devices)

Comment: Strange. It's possible it depends on the manufacturer then. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SERIAL string from android.os.build class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL

Answer (score -2):

add `android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"` to your manifest

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);    
String id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score -3):

If u want to get android_id , u can use

```
 private String getAndroidID() {
            String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            return androidId;
        }
```

In case u want device id , u can use

```
private TelephonyManager getTelephonyManager() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
        return telephonyManager;
    }

private String getIMEIStringOfDevice() {
       String imeiString = getTelephonyManager().getDeviceId(); 
        return imeiString;
    }
```

Comment: No, I want number that adb returns. I already wrote that non of these return number that is in example.

Comment: Thanks for writing the programmatic way, but adb command is needed.